# The connection was not closed. The connection's current state is open

Tags: vb.net, ado.net

```
Try
    If functionmode = "ADD" Then
        SQLStr = "INSERT INTO boatmast VALUES ('" & gBoatType & "','" & TxtBoatCode.Text & "','" & TxtBoatName.Text & "','" & Format(txtBP.Text, "##0.#0") & "','" & Format(txtBPM.Text, "##0.#0") & "','" & Format(txtLDA.Text, "##0.#0") & "','" & , 'bpk', '" & Today & "', '" & updtime & "', 'bpk', '" & Today & "', '" & updtime & "')"
    End If
    conn.Open()
    SQLCmd.Connection = conn
    SQLCmd.CommandText = SQLStr
    SQLCmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    conn.Close()


Catch ex As OdbcException
    MsgBox(ex.ToString)
Finally
    conn.Close()
End Try
```

Comment: This code is vulnerable to sql injection attacks.

Comment: Insert into SQL the values of textbox.text is a *REALLY* bad idea.

Comment: Use a stored procedure or parameterized query.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is you call conn.Close() twice. Retain your Close connection on your finally block.

```
Try

    If functionmode = "ADD" Then
                                        //Supposed this is you columnNAmes                                                     //Set parameters                 
        SQLStr = "INSERT INTO boatmast (gBoatType,BoatCode,BoatName,BP, BPM,LDA,bpk,Today,updtime,bpk2,Today2,updtime2) VALUES (@gBoatType,@BoatCode,@BoatName,@BP, @BPM,@LDA,@bpk,@Today,@updtime,@bpk2,@Today2,@updtime2)"

      SQLCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@gBoatType",gBoatType)
      //DO OTHER STUFF TIL @updtime2            

    conn.Open()
    SQLCmd.Connection = conn
    SQLCmd.CommandText = SQLStr
    SQLCmd.ExecuteNonQuery() 

  End If
Catch ex As OdbcException
    MsgBox(ex.ToString)
Finally
     If conn.State = ConnectionState.Open Then conn.Close()
End Try
```

Regards

Comment: Surely you mean to remove to the one in the `Try` block?  If `SQLCmd.ExecuteNonQuery()` fails, it will never close the connection.

Comment: Then...Place it on Finally block..Thanks Sir. I just edited my post.

Comment: maybe there is also duplicate conn.Close() on your other codes aside on what you posted.Can you post your full code? @Peterson Agas