# Connection to database not closing in VB.NET

Tags: sql, vb.net, oledb

I have the function below. Sometimes after using it I need to delete the db and re-create it but this function keeps using the database (so it cannot be deleted) even though I ask it to drop the database and close all connections. Any help would greatly be appreciated.

```
Public Function alreadyindatabase(ByVal url As String) As Boolean
    url = url.Replace("'", "''")
    Dim connetionString As String
    Dim oledbCnn As OleDbConnection
    Dim oledbCmd As OleDbCommand
    Dim sql As String

    connetionString = "PROVIDER=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" & datafile
    sql = "Select * from visitedurl Where [Field1]='" + url + "'"

    oledbCnn = New OleDbConnection(connetionString)
    Try
        oledbCnn.Open()
        oledbCmd = New OleDbCommand(sql, oledbCnn)
        Dim oledbReader As OleDbDataReader = oledbCmd.ExecuteReader()

        If oledbReader.Read Then
            'MsgBox("Found")
            Return True
        Else
            'MsgBox("Not found")
            Return False
        End If
        'While oledbReader.Read
        ' MsgBox(oledbReader.Item(0))
        'End While
        SqlConnection.ClearAllPools()
        sql = "DROP DATABASE [" & datafile & "]"
        oledbCmd = New OleDbCommand(sql)
        oledbCmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

        oledbCmd.Cancel()
        oledbReader.Close()
        oledbCmd.Connection.Close()
        oledbCnn.Close()
        oledbCmd.Dispose()
        oledbCnn.Dispose()


    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try


End Function
```

Answer (score 3):

You should have a finally section to your try catch and close the connection within there. Otherwise if an exception occurs the connection doesn't get closed.

If you have a look at this answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/8557227/465404) it will show you how.

So you might want to have it similar to this...

```
Public Function alreadyindatabase(ByVal url As String) As Boolean
    url = url.Replace("'", "''")
    Dim connetionString As String
    Dim oledbCnn As OleDbConnection
    Dim oledbCmd As OleDbCommand
    Dim sql As String

    connetionString = "PROVIDER=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" & datafile
    sql = "Select * from visitedurl Where [Field1]='" + url + "'"

    oledbCnn = New OleDbConnection(connetionString)
    Try
        oledbCnn.Open()
        oledbCmd = New OleDbCommand(sql, oledbCnn)
        Dim oledbReader As OleDbDataReader = oledbCmd.ExecuteReader()

        If oledbReader.Read Then
            'MsgBox("Found")
            Return True
        Else
            'MsgBox("Not found")
            Return False
        End If
        'While oledbReader.Read
        ' MsgBox(oledbReader.Item(0))
        'End While
        SqlConnection.ClearAllPools()
        sql = "DROP DATABASE [" & datafile & "]"
        oledbCmd = New OleDbCommand(sql)
        oledbCmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

        oledbCmd.Cancel()
        oledbReader.Close()
        oledbCmd.Connection.Close()
        oledbCnn.Close()
        oledbCmd.Dispose()
        oledbCnn.Dispose()


    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.ToString)
    Finally
         If oledbCnn.State = ConnectionState.Open Then oledbCnn.Close()
    End Try


End Function
```

Comment: +1. I Agree. Removing the close connection by twice on the `Try` could be helpful also.

Comment: Thanks that worked. I suspected this was the reason but when I entered the oledbCnn.Close() outside of the try it didn't solve the problem. Not sure what is the difference between that and using Finally maybe I need to brush up my .NET basics.

Comment: The finally section will be executed whether the try ran successfully or an exception occurred. This is very useful for places where you need to clean up resources, like closing a database connection or a file handler. Please remember to mark an answer if your question has been successfully answered.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the try catch. You're probably getting an exception, then ignoring it, which means the connection never got to close and you never found out. Alternatively, you can add a finally clause where you close the connection, since it will run no matter what.

Answer (score 0):

You are closing the connection twice:

```
oledbCmd.Cancel()
oledbReader.Close()
oledbCmd.Connection.Close()  '<--------
oledbCnn.Close()             '<--------
oledbCmd.Dispose() 
oledbCnn.Dispose()
```

Maybe, it is generating an exception that prevents the connection Dispose call.

Try to comment de first connection close attempt (oledbCmd.Connection.Close())

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Your connection will not be closed in case of an error. You can wrap the relevant sections in a [Using](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/htd05whh%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)-block (basically adds a Try-Finally automatically) and by that also shorten your code.:

```
Public Function alreadyindatabase(ByVal url As String) As Boolean
    url = url.Replace("'", "''")
    Dim connetionString As String
    Dim sql As String

    connetionString = "PROVIDER=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" & datafile
    sql = "Select * from visitedurl Where [Field1]='" + url + "'"

    Using oledbCnn = New OleDbConnection(connetionString)
        oledbCnn.Open()
        Using oledbCmd = New OleDbCommand(sql, oledbCnn)
            Using oledbReader As OleDbDataReader = oledbCmd.ExecuteReader()
            If oledbReader.Read Then
                Return True
            Else
                Return False
            End If
        End Using
        SqlConnection.ClearAllPools()
        sql = "DROP DATABASE [" & datafile & "]"
        Using oledbCmd = New OleDbCommand(sql)
            oledbCmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            oledbCmd.Cancel()
        End Using
    End Using
End Function
```